# SDL 1.2: How to determine memory usage of an SDL_Surface allocated in system memory

Tags: sdl

Is there an SDL 1.2 function which returns the memory usage allocated to an SDL_Surface pointer?

Specifically the SDL_Surface* is returned by IMG_Load().

Looking at the structure, it seems as if this would give a result in the correct ballpark:

```
SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load(image_file_name);
size_t memory = surface->w * surface->h * surface->format->BitsPerPixel / 8
```

... at least for my target architecture which has 32 bit pixels. But is there either an SDL 1.2. API function or a more accurate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no SDL 1.2 function for determining the memory usage of a surface.  If you were creating the surface yourself, not via SDL_image, then you could use a custom allocator that keeps track of the allocations.

Your code should probably be close enough of an estimate.  However, I would use the pitch instead, because there may be padding bytes on each row:

```
size_t memory_bytes = surface->pitch * surface->h;
```

(Note that this may be inappropriate for surfaces which use the SDL_RLEACCEL flag.)

If you care to be pedantic about the impact of the rest of the struct, add in:

```
sizeof(SDL_Surface)
 + sizeof(SDL_PixelFormat)
 + (surface->format->palette == NULL? 0
    : sizeof(SDL_Palette)
       + sizeof(SDL_Color) * surface->format->palette->ncolors)
```